# NumericUpDown control start from the beginning in first input

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have NumericUpDown control created dynamically like this:

```
            var numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown
            {
                Name = "numericUpDown" + Labels.Count,
                Maximum = decimal.MaxValue,
                Minimum = decimal.MinValue,
                Value = rModel[i].ContractedAmount,
                Location = new Point(12, YPos),
                Size = new Size(70, 19),
                DecimalPlaces = 4
            };
            this.Controls.Add(numericUpDown);
```

So when it loads it throw something like this:

[image]

I have an event if I clic control it select all control:

[image]

Now if I want to change value I just type I.E number 2, once that value is added cursor appears in the first place of control
[image]

So if I type a second number it just add at the first place insted at the right of number 2. So if I type 9 value is now 92. This only happen one time, because if I type more values after 92 it add after 9 correctly I.E

```
977423487342
```

But first is always at the end. Regards

Note: I can not use decimal places. If I type `.` pointer just go to first place.
Same happens if I use backspace after decimal.

TextChange event:

```
private void NumericUpDown_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         NumericWasChanged = true;

        lblCurrentAmount.Text = "0";

        foreach (Panel panel in tpnlDeliveryBreakdown.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {
            foreach (Control c in panel.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(NumericUpDown))
                {
                    var currentControl = (c as NumericUpDown);
                    lblCurrentAmount.Text = (decimal.Parse(lblCurrentAmount.Text) + decimal.Parse(currentControl.Value.ToString())).ToString();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have *something* in your code that sends `Keys.Enter` to the Control, when the Value changes? When you press `Enter` on a NumericUpDown, the content is formatted and the caret is moved to the first position. Inserting the decimal separator also doesn't move the caret, unless *something* makes it.

Comment: Yes, I have TextChange event... I added to my question @Jimi

Comment: Don't use the Text, use the `[NumericUpDown].Value`. Set the Value, don't parse and format text. The code you added doesn't do that anyway: `currentNumericUpDownValue.Value.ToString();` doesn't make sense and you're setting the Text of a Label there. The `sender` object is never used. Not the right code or edited.

Comment: You have code you aren't showing us.  None of the code you posted reproduces the problem you are describing with the selection or key pressing.  The TextChanged event is hidden in favor of the ValueChanged event.

Comment: Are you changing your code based on the comments I post? Don't do that. If you find mistakes, leave them there: if you change the code on the fly, you may introduce others that render the question mute. This is not the code that formats the NumericUpDown. You have something else. Btw, the code that creates the controls doesn't show that you're adding event handlers. Are there more? Well, the *problem* is in one of these.

Comment: I do that, because I have multiple `NumericUpDown` controls, so I want to show sum of them in a label... I debug it and problem is in that sum. When that sum occurs something happens to control and it move cursor to first place. @Jimi

Comment: Follow the chain of events, then and/or put breakpoints in all the handler you have that reference NumericUpDown controls. Btw, use the `ValueChanged`, not the `TextChanged` event . `lblCurrentAmount.Text = "0";` is useless. Add a decimal variable (`decimal sumOfValues = 0.0M`) then loop your controls, adding the `NumericUpDown.Value` to `sumOfValues`. In the end, set `lblCurrentAmount.Text = sumOfValues.ToString("N4")`. If you added more handlers to the NUDs, post that code. If you add/remove NUDs, remember to Dispose() of them and their handlers, don't use `.Controls.Remove([Control])`